# Defining a macro in C

Tags: c, macros

Lets say I define a macro:

```
#define MAX(x,y)    ((x)>(y)?(x):(y))
```

What would happen if I call `MAX(I++,J++)`?

I couldn't understand why the answer would not be as expected.

Comment: What answer did you get? What answer did you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macros are just for the preprocessor. This is what would get compiled by the C compiler:

```
(((I++)>(J++))? ((I++):(J++)))
```

As you can see, if I is larger than J then I will get incremented **twice** and J once, otherwise it's vice versa.

---

Your macro is not even correct. The outer layer of parentheses is wrong here, which will cause a compilation error:

```
((I++):(J++))
```

Comment: Worth mentioning: It is defined behavior since there is sequence point after evaluating the left operand (The boolean codition). This is not trivial in macros, for instance: `MAX(I++,I++)` would result in undefined behavior, since `I` is being increased twice in the same expression.

Answer (score 2):

`MAX(I++,J++)` would expand to `(((I++)>(J++))? ((I++):(J++)))`. Notice there are two occurrences of `I++` and `J++`, so they would both be incremented after the comparison, and then whichever is the result would be incremented again.

You could use an inline function instead:

```
inline int MAX(int x, int y)
{
    return x > y ? x : y;
}
```

But I suppose the macro has the advantage of working for any type.

Comment: As I said, I suppose the macro has the advantage of working for any type (whereas you'd need a different function for each).

Answer (score 1):

in `int res = MAX(x,y);` the macro will expend to

```
(((x) > (y)) ? (x):(y));
```

now if `x = a++` and `y = b++` that will translate into

```
(((a++) > (b++)) ? (res = a++):(res = b++));
```

thus, for the path where the condition is true, whichever variable it is will be inc twice in total but the resulting value stored in `res` will have only one increment (as you're using post incrementation).

It can be tricky to use post-inc in function/macro calls as they can introduce subtle logic glitches.

Prefer passing the variable to a function/macro as is and do whatever change to it separatly, that will save you time on that kind of issues.